# Can I add more xmlns attribute?

Tags: html

Usually my page is defined as :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="it">
```

but using a Facebook Plugin, it says :

```
Add an XML namespace to the <html> tag of your document. This is necessary for XFBML to work in earlier versions of Internet Explorer.

<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

So I wrote :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" xml:lang="it">
```

Is this correct? Or html document need only 1 xmlns?

Answer (score 3):

As long as you do not specify the DTD as XHTML Strict, multiple xmlns attributes are allowed. So it's ok.

Answer (score 2):

As you're using XHTML 1.1 it shouldn't cause any problems: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/conformance.html